# Custom module to alter display value of field

Tags: 7, theming

I have a question about custom modules. I am trying to write a module that changes the display value of a field. I think the thing I'm trying to do require a

```
hook_page_alter
```

method, and to change the field

```
$page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$nid]['body']
```

So far I'm haven't been able to change anything on the page. Would anyone have a good solution?

Comment: Is `$nid` defined in your hook invocation?

Comment: @Jill You don't need a custom module for this [hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7.x), can be equally written to your theme's template.php file

Comment: @ShawnConn no it isn't... would that be something like $page->$nid?

Comment: @mchar I know thank you... I already wrote this code into the theme, but I am trying to follow drupal best practices and put modifications into custom modules

Answer (score 0):

The example you're using in the [`hook_page_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7.x) docs isn't a valid example but a demonstration. The problem here is the variable `$nid` isn't defined in your hook invocation. The expression:

```
$page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$nid]['body']
```

isn't valid. `$page['content']['system_main']['nodes']` contains an associated array of nid/node data.

This can be one or many nodes depending on the context (e.g. front page vs. a node page). You'll need build your logic accordingly (e.g. `$nid = reset($page['content']['system_main']['nodes']`) to retrieve the specific node that you want then make the altercation as you need it.

Comment: Thanks Shawn I know. In my question I just had no idea what to use for variables. What helped was `var_dump($page)`, which allowed me to see the structure of the page (hook_page_alter wasn't the best method to use anyway -- will post my answer soon!)